# SAP GRC case start date and due date location in tables

Tags: sap-erp

Good afternoon,

Does anyone know in which table are stored a test control effectiveness planner case start date and due date in SAP GRC?

The `CREATE_TIME` attribute in the `SCMG_T_CASE_ATTR` table refers to the moment that this form is filled and the plan activated, not to the control start date.

The `DUE_DATE` column of the `GRPCCASETL` table is not always filled. It shows `00000000` many times.

Does anybody know in which table are the two dates in the red square stored?

Test Control Effectiveness Planner:

[image: Test Control Effectiveness Planner]

Comment: `CREATE_TIME` current date, no? And maybe the second date is copied from the source plan?

Comment: CREATE_TIME is not the start date. It is the date in which the plan is programmed.

Comment: Usually, by using a simple SQL trace in the ABAP stack (transaction `ST05`), and inserting/updating the object, you will find out quite easily which tables and columns are updated.